# Hibernate oneToOne with type of superclass

Tags: hibernate, polymorphism

I think I want a 1to1 relationship, but my dB skills are not the best.  I have a user class with all my spring security logic.  My user can be either an admin or a viewer.

My original thought was to have a Profile super class then have an Admin and Viewer class that extends Profile.

I could then give give my user a profile parameter.  But all my attempts failed....

I think my strategy is wrong.

**I was able to get the below working**
package com.legge.worksiteWebCams.models.profile

import com.legge.worksiteWebCams.models.abstract.RestModel
import javax.persistence.*

**superclass:**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Profile : RestModel() {
    private val name: String? = null
}
```

**Viewer**

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "viewer_id")
class Viewer : Profile() {
   //Viewer logic here
}
```

**Viewer**

```
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "admin_id")
class Admin : Profile() {
   //Admin logic here
}
```

and then i was able to reference it in
**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sec_user", uniqueConstraints = [(UniqueConstraint(columnNames = arrayOf("username"))), (UniqueConstraint(columnNames = arrayOf("email")))])
data class User(
        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade = [(CascadeType.ALL)])
        var profile: Profile? = null,
){}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use @OneToMany relationship Because User might have many roles
just like Admin and Viewer.
This is the first approach.

In User.java class

```
@OneToMany
List<Role> rol = new ArrayList<>().
```

2) Do @ManyToMany mapping because one user has many roles and one role belongs to many users.

User.java class.

```
 @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "UserRole",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "accountId",
                referencedColumnName = "id") ,
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "roleId",
                referencedColumnName = "id") )
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Comment: Ty so much for getting back to me!  I will try out your suggestion.  I also have a one to one that worked and i will list it...